# How to always run n processes parallel, without waiting previous n processes to finish?

Tags: python, python-3.x, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

I have 50 different methods that I want to run. I have 10 cpus available, so I can run only 10 processes at the same time. So I run them 5 times. However, the problem is first 10 processes should finish in order to start the second 10 processes, and this increases the time needed to finish. What I want is as soon as 9 processes are running a new process should start and always run 10 processes.

I put my 50 classes to 5 different groups and run.

group1 = [class1, class2...]
group2 = [class11, class12..]

groups = [group1, group2, ..., group5]

```
for group in groups:

    threads = []

        for x in group:
            threads.append(mp.Process(target= x().method(), args= (b,)))

        for thread in threads:
            thread.start()

        for thread in threads:
            thread.join()
```

Comment: Check out `multiprocessing.Pool`.

Comment: As mentioned above, your problem is solved by [Worker Pools](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#using-a-pool-of-workers). Keep in mind that your main body code also occupies a thread, unless it's sleeping!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should create a Pool of processes and use the apply_async method:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
pool = Pool(processes=10) # start 10 worker processes
for arg in args:
  pool.apply_async(yourFunc, args = (arg, ))
pool.close()
pool.join()
```

https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html